# Why does Devise give me an error about being signed in for this action which surely should require being signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Rails 4 with Devise. Devise comes with existing forms to set the password so I wanted to add a link for the user to change their own password once logged in.

In my view, I have:

```
  <li><%= link_to 'Change password', edit_user_password_path %></li>
```

This appears to render the right link:

```
<a href="/users/password/edit">Change password</a>
```

When I try to visit this page, I get a flash message saying "You are already signed in", and the logs show:

```
Started GET "/users/password/edit" for ::1 at 2016-07-05 16:46:17 +1000
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

So I can see it hits the right controller and the right action, but then mysteriously redirects.

I don't really understand what this means but I would have thought that the page to edit your password would only work when signed in, so I'm not really sure why I'm getting an error about already being signed in.

Does anyone know Devise well enough to explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edit_user_password_path` is used for forgot password page, you need `edit_user_registration_path`.

Comment: This sounds right, but it seems like edit_user_registration_path is unavailable by default: "undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff63f0b1228>:0x007ff63a71d7b0>" Indeed, when I look at my routes, I don't see any routes with "registration" mentioned. Possibly also relevant is that users cannot register their own accounts on this site, so I couldn't use :registerable in my model.

Comment: @Trejkaz in that case you need to create own controller and view for that purpose. You can use devise analogues as the source of inspiration xD https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L37

Comment: What I will probably do is resurrect my old password editing page and adapt it to use as much devise stuff as I can. I have to do another custom action for admins resetting a user password at some point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use:

```
edit_user_registration_path
```